# jQuery .load() fails to load style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to implement Infinite Scroll feature in a Wordpress based site (Yes, there are lot of plugins around for Infinite Scroll. I tested around and I would like to have my own as none of them could work 100%). In general my implementation work (of course with the help of samples around the web). The basic idea is, when I reach the footer, jQuery load() call is used to load the next set of posts.

In functions.php, I added the following:

```
function include_infinite_scroll_js() {
    if( !is_singular() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-infinite-scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.infinitescroll.js', array('jquery') );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_infinite_scroll_js');
```

jquery.infinitescroll.js is from https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js

```
function add_infinite_scroll_to_footer() {
    if( !is_singular() ) {
    ?>
    <div id="infinite-scroll-wrap">
        <?php next_posts_link('Next page'); ?>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.content').infinitescroll({
                navSelector : "#infinite-scroll-wrap",
                nextSelector : "#infinite-scroll-wrap a:first",
                itemSelector : ".posts",
                debug : true,
                loading: {
                    msgText : 'Loading Next Posts...',
                    finishedMsg : 'No more Posts left! :('
                },
                animate : false,
                dataType : 'html'
            });
            jQuery('.archive-nav').remove();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_infinite_scroll_to_footer');
```

I use 2 `<div>` elements. Only the content of 2nd `<div>` (with class named "posts") will be appended to the 1st `<div>` (with the class named ".content"). This is handled with the following piece of code from jquery.infinitescroll.js:

```
box.load(desturl + ' ' + opts.itemSelector, undefined, function infscr_ajax_callback(responseText) {
   instance._loadcallback(box, responseText, desturl);
});
```

as a result, from next page, the "posts" `<div>` is retrieved and added to the "content" `<div>` of the original page without "style" attribute and `<span>` as shown in the picture below:

[content after the jQuery load()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2YjZ.jpg)

On left side of the image, I marked the posts elements and the style and span that will disappear from the right side of the image after the next page was loaded with the help of load().

Yes, I checked the stylesheets were still present after the load() function was executed. I used this piece of code to see if all links from `<head>` are same before and after. It was same.

```
instance._debug("links after");
var links = window.document.getElementsByTagName('link');
$(links).each(function() {
    instance._debug($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I am unable to figure out what is making the "style" (and span) to disappear after the load(). I would like to have your inputs on this and appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the `style` and the `span` elements you are missing are added dynamically to your page by a script. In that case you have to figure out which scripts those are and call them after appending your posts. Also keep in mind that when features are missing they most likely haven't been added at all – unless you're working in an inverse fashion. And if the features `disappeared` when compared one DOM to another, it doesn't mean that the same relation holds for comparison between the actual DOM and the features themselves...

Comment: @Bright, thank you.

It appears that is the case or at least there is a jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... } function which does some activity. From my add_infinite_scroll_to_footer(), ready() is invoked as well when I hit the footer. How do I get to invoke/call (explicitly) the original ready()?

Comment: With the hint provided by @Bright, I had look at the document [link](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) which says:
"In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead."
I duplicated the code from original ready(), which made the style to appear again. This indicates that after the load(), it is necessary to reapply the style.

Once again, thank you Bright.